# Laravel: How to get the foreign key by convention

Tags: laravel

I have two tables:

```
products: id, slug...
product_translations: id, product_id, name
```

How to get product_id in product_translation?

Now I'm doing this:

```
$upsertData = ...
$this->translationModel()->upsert($upsertData,['id', $translationModel->foreign_key, 'locale']);
```

ProductTranslation.php

```
class ProductTranslation extends Model
{
    public $foreign_key = 'product_id';
    ...
```

If I can get the foreign key, I don't need to define in AnyTranslation model.

Or, how to get 'product_id' from $product ?

---

To make it more clear, if it's a product record, then:

```
$this->translationModel()->upsert($upsertData,['id', 'product_id', 'locale']);
```

If it's a post, then

```
$this->translationModel()->upsert($upsertData,['id', 'post_id', 'locale']);
```

Now I use $this->foreign_key to replace that

```
$this->translationModel()->upsert($upsertData,['id', $translationModel->foreign_key, 'locale']);
```

So, is there other better way to get the foreign key. singular table name + _id

Comment: *Or, how to get 'product_id' from $product ?* is `$product` initiated or am I missing something?

Comment: $product is initiated, it's a record previous get. And $product is just an example, it could be $member, $post... .  What I want is, If $product, then get 'product_id', not the big integer value of the column product_id, but product_id literally, if $member, then get member_id. You can see my code of upsert(...) again, Is it possible not to use foreign_key.

Comment: When you ask questions, be present to respond. Someone here will answer this or Open Bounty to draw the attention.

Answer (score 0):

In your translations model:

```
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

In your product model:

```
public function translations() {
    return $this->hasMany(Translation::class);
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
Product::with('translations')....
```

For the display you would use something like:

```
foreach($product->translations as $trasnlation) // If this is ever needed
```

or

```
Translation::with('product')...
```

Regarding the migrations in trasnlations table add:

```
$table->foreign('product_id')->constrained('products')->onDelete('cascade') // or on delete put "NULL"
```

Although, you should use some package preferrably that is using json files :)

Good luck

Comment: I know what you said, but that's not my question. My question is not 'with', but how to upsert() the translation model. "How to save a relationship" is a solution,too. But upsert() maybe faster. I also used translation package before. For some reason, I don't use it any more.